# Searching for tweets in last 24 hours from specific accounts with twitter API in python

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots

Instead of '2016-11-25' / '2016-11-27', what should I put in if I only want results from the last 24 hours? I also only want tweets from some specific accounts so what should I write inside the api search?

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q='giveaway',
                       since='2016-11-25',
                       until='2016-11-27',
                       ).items(10):
print('Tweet by: @' + tweet.user.screen_name)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with tweepy (looks like fun though, I'll have to try it).

but maybe check out page 6-7 here: http://coding2day.com/TwitterPython.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting tweets by date with tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362651/getting-tweets-by-date-with-tweepy)

Answer (score 1):

Use the datetime module

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.today().now()
prev=now-timedelta(days=1)
now=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
prev=prev.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                   q='giveaway',
                   since=prev
                   until=now
                   ).items(10):
print('Tweet by: @' + tweet.user.screen_name)
```