# Tweepy get tweets by date

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to get tweets for a certain topic between dates. Is this possible in tweepy? (or any other API for twitter?)

I can get it working for user_timeline by using the IDs, but when I change it to use api.search the program basically just keeps on running without any output

```
def getTweets(username):
    tweets = []
    tmpTweets = api.user_timeline(username, tweet_mode = 'extended', include_rts=True)
    for tweet in tmpTweets:
        if tweet.created_at < endDate and tweet.created_at > startDate:
            tweets.append(tweet)

        while (tmpTweets[-1].created_at > startDate):
            tmpTweets = api.user_timeline(username, max_id = tmpTweets[-1].id,tweet_mode = 'extended')
            for tweet in tmpTweets:
                if tweet.created_at < endDate and tweet.created_at > startDate:
                    tweets.append(tweet)
    return tweets
```

***tl;dr:*** Is there a way in python to get tweets between two dates based on keyword search?

Comment: Yes, but the free search API only covers the past 7 days. That's the Twitter API not Tweepy.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a *[cursor](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/cursor_tutorial.html)*:

```
text_query = 'Coronavirus'
since_date = '2020-02-10'
until_date = '2020-08-10'
max_tweets = 150

# Creation of query method using parameters
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=text_query, since=since_date, until=until_date).items(max_tweets)
```

Also described in this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-scrape-more-information-from-tweets-on-twitter-44fd540b8a1f) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57837143).